# OnVideoChatChangeState() usage in Quickblox

Tags: android, quickblox, videochat

I am using quickblox api for 1 to 1 videochat but I dont know the usage `OnVideoChatChangeState()` of `OnQBVideoChatListener()` class and with what changes the event is invoked. I have modified the code but the video doesnt start the click functions but doesn't go to:

```
` public void onVideoChatStateChange(CallState state, VideoChatConfig receivedVideoChatConfig) {
                videoChatConfig = receivedVideoChatConfig;
                isCanceledVideoCall = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "switch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                switch (state) 
                {
                    case ON_CALLING:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "After this the showCallDialog() will be called.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        showCallDialog();                      
                        break;
                    case ON_ACCEPT_BY_USER:
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        startVideoChatActivity();
                        break;
                    case ON_REJECTED_BY_USER:
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case ON_DID_NOT_ANSWERED:
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                    case ON_CANCELED_CALL:
                        isCanceledVideoCall = true;
                        videoChatConfig = null;
                        break;
                    case ON_START_CONNECTING:
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        startVideoChatActivity();
                        break;
                    default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
`
```

and the `showCallDialog();` method is not called this shows the events doesn't occur here.
So I want to know can the event occurs so that the methods are called.

Comment: Just look at https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-android. You should register listener throw QBVideoChatService.getService().setQBVideoChatListener(currentQbUser, qbVideoChatListener);

Comment: I did all the things in that available in sample videochat, also used the `QBVideoChatServicegetService.setQBVideoChattListener(currentQbUser, qbVideoChatListener); ` but it doesnt go through OnVideoChatStateChange() function and if it goes the videochatchange events occurs with the current user logged in it doesnt effect on the other side where another user is logged and we want to have video chat with that user.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed. Master branch is updated. Please try [download](https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-android) and use the sample once again.